# How to render a single JSON property using jQueryTemplate

Tags: json, jquery-templates

Whats the simplest way to render a single JSON property using [jQueryTemplate](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest would be something like:

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script id="mainTmpl" type="text/html">
    <span>${message}</span>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = {
    message: "hello world"
  };
  $("#mainTmpl").tmpl(data).appendTo("#content");
</script>
```

If you didn't want to define a template, you could even do:

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = {
    message: "hello world"
  };
  $("<span>${message}</span>").tmpl(data).appendTo("#content");
</script>
```

If you just passing in a single value, then you could use $data to access it like:

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script id="mainTmpl" type="text/html">
    <span>${$data}</span>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = "hello world";
  $("#mainTmpl").tmpl(data).appendTo("#content");
</script>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2evHS/

Comment: The type attribute shouldn't be "text/x-jquery-tmpl" instead of "text/html"?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Neither is enforced, it is just convention.